# Error-logging for javascript on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, stack-trace

My project which contains a lot of pages with forms. This is a backend of banking CRM system, so any error during working process is to be captured and investigated. 
On the server side we have enhanced java exceptions system, but if error occurs on client side - javascript the only info we now get is an js-error window in IE or sometimes a screenshot of page made by advanced user.

Javascript code contains both Jquery-powered UI extensions and hard-coded inline event handlers and functions.

So I am asking whether any approach for capturing js-errors of any kind could be used? 
some additional library or something that could give me a stacktrace like firebug in Mozilla or web-console in Chrome?

Comment: refer to this link: http://openmymind.net/2012/4/4/You-Really-Should-Log-Client-Side-Error/

Comment: I haven't tried that on my own, but solutions like that, might look interesting: https://www.proxino.com/

Comment: Thanks to Tamil and Alexanderb, but in my case I can't use outsourcing and located not inside my network area services

Comment: can we do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134563/how-to-log-client-side-exceptions-in-stackexchange-exceptional

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look into `window.onerror`. If you want to capture any errors, and report them to the server, then you could try an AJAX request, perhaps.

```
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, errorUrl, errorLine) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jserror.jsf',
        data: {
            msg: errorMessage,
            url: errorUrl,
            line: errorLine
        },
        success: function() {
            if (console && console.log) {
                console.log('JS error report successful.');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            if (console && console.error) {
                console.error('JS error report submission failed!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Prevent firing of default error handler.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should add a throttling function to this. If the client falls into a loop that generates errors, the clients will DOS your logging endpoint quickly. Check out this Repo for a great example. https://github.com/TrackJs/Tech-Demo

Comment: contentType needs to be 'application/json'

Comment: data needs to be JSON stringified : data: JSON.stringify

Answer (score 21):

Disclaimer: I'm CEO and creator of [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com), an open source and paid service which does crash reporting for many languages, including Javascript.

It can be pretty challenging to capture frontend exceptions. Technology has gotten better (browser JS engines), but there's still a lot of limitations.

1. You're going to need a server-side logging endpoint. This has a few complexities as it's possible to abuse it (i.e. PEN testers may try to expose vulnerabilities in it). You also need to deal with CORS here. I'd obviously recommend Sentry for this, as we're best in class, and if you want you can host the server yourself (as its open source).
2. The implementation of actually capturing the errors in your code is pretty complicated. You cant rely on `window.onerror` for various reasons (mostly because browsers historically give bad information here). What we do in the [raven.js](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js) client (which is based on TraceKit) is patch a number of functions to wrap them in try/catch statements. For example, `window.setTimeout`. With this we're able to install error handlers that will generate full stacktraces in most browsers.
3. You'll want to ensure you're generating sourcemaps for your code, and that the server handling the data supports them. Sentry does this both by scraping them automatically (via the standards) or allowing you to upload them via an [API](https://gist.github.com/dcramer/619d53dabfbc2ed008a1). Without this, assuming you're minifying code, things become almost unusable.
4. The last major issue is noise. Most browser extensions will inject directly into your scripts so you need to filter out the noise. We solve this in two ways: a blacklist of patterns to ignore (i.e. "Script error." being the most useless), as well as a whitelist of domains to accept (i.e. "example.com"). We've found the combination of the two being effective-enough at removing most random noise.

Some things you should be aware of on the server:

- Clients will sometimes persist open (i.e. a bot, or a bad user) and cause large amounts of useless data or simple old errors.
- Your server should be able to handle a cascade of these events and fail gracefully. Sentry does this by rate limiting things and sampling data.
- Exceptions are localized into the browser language, and without a centralized database you will be stuck translating them yourself (though its generally obvious what they mean).

Answer (score 4):

If your website is using Google Analytics, you can do what I do:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  if (error) message = error.stack;
  ga('send', 'event', 'window.onerror', message, navigator.userAgent);
}
```

A few comments on the code above:

- For modern browsers, the full stack trace is logged.
- For older browsers that don't capture the stack trace, the error message is logged instead. (Mostly earlier iOS version in my experience).
- The user's browser version is also logged, so you can see which OS/browser versions are throwing which errors. That simplifies bug prioritization and testing.
- This code works if you use Google Analytics with "analytics.js", [like this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). If you are using "gtag.js" instead, [like this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/), you need to tweak the last line of the function. [See here for details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events).

Once the code is in place, this is how you view your users' Javascript errors:

1. In Google Analytics, click the `Behavior` section and then the `Top Events` report.
2. You will get a list of Event Categories. Click `window.onerror` in the list.
3. You will see a list of Javascript stack traces and error messages. Add a column to the report for your users' OS/browser versions by clicking the `Secondary dimension` button and entering `Event Label` in the textbox that appears.
4. The report will look like the screenshot below.
5. To translate the OS/browser strings to more human-readable descriptions, I copy-paste them into https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do painless implementation just put up [this](http://errorception.com) guys javascript code in your app. Else If you want to implement one, then try [this](http://helephant.com/2007/05/12/diy-javascript-stack-trace/) to get the stacktrace on `window` `error` and you can use `ajax` to report the errors. A [nice way](https://www.olark.com/spw/2012/03/dont-break-the-internet-with-your-javascript/) to track errors reported by olark

Answer (score 2):

http://exceptionhub.com 
Should to the trick.
http://errorception.com/
Does not provide as much information for debugging, but also seems nice.

proxino don't seem to know what they are doing, they where incuding a complete jQuery in their logger code to log onerror events last time i checked. I wouldn't trust a service that has so little grasp of client side JavaScript to log my JavaScript errors.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Proxino also has a jQuery-less version of the script, though it still requires you to load jQuery on your page. https://www.proxino.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [JsLog.me](http://jslog.me) service

It can capture whole console output in addition to errors and stacktraces. We use it in our projects, logging whole console log helps our QA team to record issue-reproduction way. Also, it works well with large JSON objects like in Chrome console, and has a search.

Answer (score 0):

[Atatus](https://www.atatus.com/) captures JavaScript errors and also captures the user actions that preceded the error. This would help in better understanding of the error. Atatus helps you in monitoring your frontend, not just for errors, but also its performance(Real User Monitoring)

https://www.atatus.com/

Disclaimer: I’m a web developer at Atatus.