# How to catch and report the "Refused to execute script from because its MIME type (…) and strict MIME type (…)" issue?

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling, mime-types

In my web application, in non-deterministic conditions, I experience the:
*"Refused to execute script from because its MIME type (…) and strict MIME type (…)" issue.*

Is it possible to somehow detect this issue occurring on client side and report it to the server or some log tool?

From what I see it is possible to [catch errors with the windoww.onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257330/error-logging-for-javascript-on-client-side) handler but in that case we are dealing with a browser check and not an error per se.

Comment: Seems to be hard to get much specific error detail. You can play with `<script src="foo.bar" onerror="console.log(event)"></script>`. Can get the target and the target.src from event object but not much in the way of messages which I think is by security design. See section [element.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#element.onerror)

Comment: looking for an answer, need to filter out this type of error from the rest