# How to track user steps

Tags: javascript, user-input

We have a intermittent bug that **it's been hard to track**, the bug consists in randomly (so we think) when redeeming a code, the entire code value disappears upon making the order...

Doing our self the same process manually, it does not, never ever, happen!

So I thought recording the user actions, every action:

- click links
- submit inputs
- page views

ended up making up this set of rules, and appending to the end of the master page:

```
$(function() {

    // log this page view
    log2Loggly('Page View', '');

    // for each click
    $("a").click(function() { 
        var ref = $(this).attr("onclick").length > 0 ? $(this).attr("onclick") : $(this).attr("href");
        log2Loggly('Link clicked', ref);
    });

    // forms
    $("form").submit(function() { 
        var dt = $(this).serialize();
        log2Loggly('Form submited', dt);
    });
});
```

and using [Loggly](http://loggly.com/) I can send each action, as they get the hold of the date and IP, it's easier to match a user IP upon our system.

I keep seeing this services like [CrazyEgg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) that record all user actions, but we can't match the user, it's anonymous data!

What I really liked was to search for IP and get the entire user tree as kind'a of an organigram of what the user did... maybe I'm able to pull this off with the data I have, but I would like to ask 2 things prior to adventure on this idea

1. Is there any kind of service for this outthere that you might come across before?
2. what more should I track to make it "almost perfect"?

Comment: You should use event delegation, on `document` level.

Comment: I'm trying not to mess up with code, or I would probably create a way to Log everything based on [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features)

Comment: maybe add error logging, loosely like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-clientside-javascript-errors-on-server