# Is there any global javascript error handler? (even is it possible with just chrome or Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, error-handling

Javascript applications are growing day by day and getting complex too.
so is there possible to handle uncatched error that occured in app so they can be send back to server for further analysis.

i just see in phpmyadmin app sometimes show a little popup in bottom say that javascript error occurred would you like to send to server.

I am not asking about try catch or block level error handling instead i want to know weather is it possible to handle global errors just like any browser show in console/log areas. if yes then how.

Ohh sorry.. got answers
[Logging Clientside JavaScript Errors on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-clientside-javascript-errors-on-server?rq=1)

Comment: Wait, do you know there is a console in most browsers? Or is the question how would you intercept console errors and send them to the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging Clientside JavaScript Errors on Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-clientside-javascript-errors-on-server)

Comment: yes.. now i can't delete it.. just going to accept belwo answer.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTML `onerror` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) may be what you want.