# How to update JavaScript Error class

Tags: javascript, error-handling, interface, runtime-error

I want when any one of 
**EvalError, RangeError, ReferenceError, SyntaxError, TypeError, URIError** is thrown through my code I want to these error should thrown after an ajex request so that I can get to know analyse the client error logs.

When I went deep, I found that sevral interface are created for these error by extending Error class e.g.

```
interface TypeError extends Error {
}
interface TypeErrorConstructor {
    new (message?: string): TypeError;
    (message?: string): TypeError;
    prototype: TypeError;
}

declare var TypeError: TypeErrorConstructor;  



interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
    new (message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

So is there any way to redefine/update these interface defination so before throwing these error it should make an ajex request to the server.

**Note:** *I dont want to use windows.onerror* since some other library(rollbar) has own onerror implimentation.

Is it possible to redefine these interface. e.g.
I can redefine console.log as follows:

```
console.log=function(){
   return arguments;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging Clientside JavaScript Errors on Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-clientside-javascript-errors-on-server)

Comment: that's not javascript, so, not sure how it's relevant to your needs

Comment: I dont want to use windows.onerror. Is there any way to update these defination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue , solved it by redefining error class

As follows:

```
var Error = {
       name: this.name,
       message: this.message,
       toString: function () {
            window.Rollbar.error("Something went wrong", this.message );     
             ......
            return this.message;
       }
   };
```