# Logging Client side JavaScript Errors on Server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Logging Client side JavaScript Errors on Server with function name,Line number,File name.Handling error on page load and button click.How to write the error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging Clientside JavaScript Errors on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-clientside-javascript-errors-on-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a controller `ErrorController` with `Log` action, in this `controller` you save error information to DB using Entity Framework.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize]
 public JsonResult Log(ErrorModel error)
 {
       var message = error.message;
       var url = error.url;
       //dbContext save to Log table  
 }
```

If you concern about security testing, you can add attribute `Authorize` on action.

In client side implement onerror event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Error/Log',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { message: msg, url: url, linenumer: linenumber },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { // handle if need },
});
};
</script>
```